# How can I define `unlines` function generically?

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming

I would like to define a `unlines` function which works which any Sequence whose elements conform to the StringProtocol; this is my attempt:

```swift
func unlines<S: StringProtocol>(_ xs: Sequence<S>) -> S {
    return xs.joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

> Error: Use of protocol 'Sequence' as a type must be written 'any Sequence'

A version defined for a concrete type does work:

```swift
func unlines(_ xs: [String]) -> String {
    return xs.joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

but can only be applied with list of String.

How can I develop a general definition ?

EDIT:

For example, I would like to apply it to the following value:

```swift
["Hello", "World"].lazy.map { $0.lowercased() }
```

Comment: Why do you have a generic type parameter `A` that is not used?

Comment: Mistake. I'll delete it.

Comment: Am I missing something? `["Hello", "World"].lazy.map { $0.lowercased() }.joined(separator: "\n")` already works as-is

Comment: @Alexander, of course. As you noted, the code you provided works perfectly. I just wanted to create a generic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joined` returns a String so you need to change the return type and use `any Sequence`

```
func unlines<S: StringProtocol>(_ xs: any Sequence<S>) -> String {
    return xs.joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

This then works both with String and Substring

String example:

```
let result = unlines(["A", "B", "C"])
```

Substring example:

```
let result = unlines("A-B-C".split(separator: "-"))
```

both returns

> A
> B
> C

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly ! Could you explain what's this `any` word ? How did you find it ?

Comment: It's a pretty new addition to the Swift language, see for instance [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.6/existential-any)

Comment: I heard about the keyword "some" before, but never about "any". Do you think there is a difference between "some" and "any" in this specific example ? I am not sure, but for some reason perhaps better to use "some" to restrict to a single concrete type in the input ? But, now thinking better, there is no difference using "some" vs "any" in the parameter. Is that right ?

Comment: `some` would be better here. It's slightly more efficient because it avoids creating an existential container. (But the difference is slight. I wouldn't fret too much. It's just often better to reach for `some` rather than `any` when you can.)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you'd typically use a protocol extension to define instance functions that should operate on an instance, rather than using free functions that take a first argument.

Here's how that might work:

```swift
extension Sequence where Element: StringProtocol {
    // FIXME: This is a pretty Haskelly, non-Swifty name
    func unlines() -> String {
        joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}

let input = ["Hello", "World"]
    .lazy
    .map { $0.lowercased() }
    .unlines()

print(input)
// Prints:
// hello
// world
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and mentioning Haskell ! +1. Why do you say it's non-swifty ? Aren't functions defined inside extensions common in Swift ?

Comment: "Aren't functions defined inside extensions common in Swift ?" Heh, the way you phrased this ("aren't" instead of "are") makes it sound like you're skeptical or surprised. It's just a different paradigm of programming. Swift (like Java, Python, Ruby, ...) is a programming language with single-dispatch subtype polymorphism. The first argument to any method (e.g. the `a` in `a.f(b, c)` is treated specially than all the rest, because its the one whose implementation gets invoked. That's why it gets privileged with special syntax, as opposed to `f(a, b, c)`.

Comment: Very interesting ! Thank you ! So, how would you define your extension to make it more "swifty" ?

Comment: @F.Zer The code is actually fine, but I think `unlines` is a pretty non-informative that'll require readers to jump-to-definition . Frankly, I probably wouldn't extract a function for this, I think just calling `.joined(separator: "\n")` is clearer.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Why am I defining generic functions, instead of extending protocols ? Because, I call my functions in a curried way, and I benefit from partial application. Can you take advantage of partial application if you use methods in Swift ?

Comment: Yep, the type of `StringProtocol.unlines` is something like `(any Sequence<some StringProtocol>) -> () -> String)`. As much as I love Haskell, I’d caution not to write haskell in Swift unless you found parts that are particularly advantageous. You see this in JS too, where people get way too deep into curried gobblygook (I’ve literally seen people write functions to abstract out `if` by calling one of too blocks, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56901718/3141234)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251325/discussion-between-f-zer-and-alexander).